# Алгоритм выпадения картинки с учетом процента для выпадния

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм, node.js, математика

Приветствую, не могу доработать алгоритм с учетом процента для выпадения картинки.
Есть некоторые картинки, частота выпадения которых зависит от выставленного процента в админке. 
На сколько я понимаю нужно смотреть на историю выпадений.
У меня есть такой алгоритм:
  Я суммирую количество выпадений каждой картинки в единое число и делю на 100 (принимает это за единицу).
  Далее для каждой картинки: (чисто что выше я умножаю на процент выпадения) - это количество раз для выпадения.

Но, я что-то не учел и алгоритм не работает должным образом, к тому же нету рандома, картинки будут выпадать до тех пор, пока не набьют своё максимальное количество и далее переход к следующей картинке.

Прошу помочь в разработке данного алгоритма. 
Если кто-то уже делал подобное на любом языке программирования, поделитесь кодом или помогите с алгоритмом.

Спасибо

Comment: Формулировка "частота выпадения зависит от выставленного процента" подразумевает два возможных толкования: 1) число показываемых картинок не ограничено, но каждая показывается с определенной вероятностью (две картинки с вероятностями 33% и 67% при 100 показах будут показаны примерно 33 и 67 раз соответственно, при 1000 - 333 и 667). 2) Число показов строго фиксировано, после показа картинки определенное количество раз она не будет показана больше никогда (при 100 показах 1-я будет показана ровно 33 раза, 2-я — ровно 67 раз, при попытке показать 101-ю картинку возникает ошибка).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если знаем, сколько запланировано выпадений всех картинок, то умножаем его на процент выпадения конкретной картинки и получаем, сколько раз ей можно выпасть. Когда исчерпает лимит, исключаем её из претендентов на очередное выпадение.

Если не знаем, сколько выпадений будет, но знаем, сколько уже было, то пересчитываем лимит после каждого нового выпадения. Когда выпадает очередная картинка, общее число выпадений увеличивается на единицу. Из-за этого меняется текущий процент выпадения для каждой из картинок. Выбираем следующее выпадение между теми, чей плановый процент не превышает текущий.

Если неправильно понял задачу, поправьте в комментариях или в формулировке вопроса :)

Answer (score 1):

Все ваши картинки нумеруются и номера заносятся в большой массив - по столько раз, сколько картинка должна выпасть. Всё. Массив можно перемешивать, можно оставить как есть - неважно. Общий размер - скажем, `N`,  элементы массива от 1 до `N`.

Для вывода очередной картинки генерируем случайное число от 1 до `N`, смотрим, что именно лежит в этом элементе массива, какой номер картинки. Выводим ее. Меняем этот элемент массива с элементом `N`. Теперь у нас в массиве от 1 до `N-1` лежат еще непросмотренные картинки.

На следующем шаге генерируем случайное число от 1 до `N-1`, смотрим, что именно лежит в этом элементе массива, какой номер картинки. Выводим ее. Меняем этот элемент массива с элементом `N-1`. Теперь у нас в массиве от 1 до `N-2` лежат еще непросмотренные картинки.

Дальше повторять, думаю, не надо? :)